# Call one ActionResult in MVC app to export .xls and .pdf files

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want from the different button (one for .xls, one for.pdf ) in view, call one ActionResult in my Controller.

I was thinking only to change parameters, but I don't know how to call them in my Response.AddHeader?!
I have something like this:

```
  string exportType = "Excel";
  string exportExtension = ".xls";

  byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
  Response.Clear();
  Response.ContentType = mimeType;

  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=GeneralOverviewAnnualAwards.xls");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in view I have this dropdown to chose action:

```
            <div class="btn-group col-sm-2">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle">Export to <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Controller/ExportExcel?id=" + 1 + "&reportType=" + 1)">Excel</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/Controller/ExportExcel?id=" + 1 + "&reportType=" + 2)">Pdf</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and in my Controller I call action with two parameters:

```
                    [HttpGet]
public ActionResult ExportExcel(int? id, int? reportType)
{


    List<pr_ReportData_Result> model = Context.pr_ReportData().ToList();


    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    try
    {

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty, encoding = string.Empty, extension = string.Empty;

        viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        //viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;

        if (id == 1)
        {
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/RDLC/Name1.rdlc");
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/RDLC/Name2.rdlc");
        }


        string exportType = String.Empty;
        string exportExtension = String.Empty;
        if (reportType == 1)
        {
            exportType = "Excel";
            exportExtension = ".xls";
        }
        else if (reportType == 2)
        {
            exportType = "PDF";
            exportExtension = ".pdf";
        }

        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsReportData", model));

        viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
        byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render(exportType, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;

        if (id == 1)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName1" + exportExtension);
        }
        else if (id == 2)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=fileName2" + exportExtension);
        }



        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        return null;

    }
    finally
    {
        if (viewer != null)
        {
            viewer.Dispose();
            viewer = null;
        }
    }

}
```

In this way I do not have repeat code in my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is. Do you want to know how to call one method in one controller from two different places in the View? If yes, here is the answer.

In your View, you need to have two `form`elements with the same action. In each form you need to have one `hidden` `input` element with the value set to "xls" or "pdf" (one for each form). Alternative approach would be to have one form and one action but also have switch/checkbox/radiobox which defines format and is passed in the view model to your controller. But you have mentioned that you want two separate buttons.

On the controller side you want to accept view model which has that hidden parameter. This way you have you parameter, like `model.format` and you are free to use it in your code.

Comment: At this moment I have only one button (and there is a 10 actually) to call Action to export .xls and for that I use one parameter. Now I need to add for each of them also option (another button) to do export to pdf. I don't want to repeat the same code and because that I try to find the most elegant solution

Comment: @koda5 - Do you want to have a button which invokes action upon click, or you are good with having a checkbox or radiobox to choose which format to export to?

Comment: Upon click - for sure.

Comment: @koda5 - If you don't use javascript (but rather plain ASP forms) you should not have two submit buttons on the same form. And even if you do, you won't know which button triggered submit. That's why I recommend having one form element per button, and bind them all to the same action (no code duplication). In the action, you may see which form triggered that action and decide which format to export to.

Comment: I find solution with dropdown menu like you said @Dmytro. Thank's a lot, your advice help me.

Comment: @koda5 - Glad to hear it! Wouldn't you mind accepting the answer then, so that others (and me) can benefit. Will appreciate it.